# How to manipulate date_select to show customized months? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, date, activeview

I   need  my date select form field to show users only the future **dates** (like for eg. today is 7 apr 2016, then it must show all dates beyond 7 apr 2016) and for **month** field it must only show the current month,**year**(any)

```
 <%= f.date_select :start_date,class: 'form-control'%>
```

[image: Date picker]

**Year:** *any*

**Date:** *only future dates*

**Month:** *the current ongoing month*

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- First is that, you validate the date before saving it, at model level. If date is note in future don't save and return error.
- Second, you can use jQuery Date Picker and use its minDate option: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Using date_select you only have the option of restricting the starting year but not month and day. http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select

```
<%= f.date_select :start_date, start_year: Date.today.year, class: 'form-control'%>
```